# How to get information about scaled up pods in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Kubernetes cluster and I am figuring out in what numbers have pods got scaled up using the **Kubectl** command.

what is the possible way to get the details of all the scaled-up and scaled-down pods within a month?

Answer (score 2):

That is not information Kubernetes records. The Events system keeps some debugging messages that include stuff about pod startup and sometimes shutdown, but that's only kept for a few hours. For long term metrics look at something like Prometheus + kube-state-metrics.

Answer (score 0):

If you have k8s audit Policy in place, you can find the Events that are passed through the k8s API by filtering them in **Cloud Audit Logs** or elasticsearch! it depends on you current setup!